# Using ag-grid in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ag-grid

In my application there are four tabs.In each tab I want to display different dataset.For the time being I have define only 2 datasets.When I do the code as below,It gives an error saying **too many re-renders**.I can't understand how to assign datasets in the **tabPanel** function
Can you please explain me a way to assign datasets for each tab separately

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import { AgGridColumn, AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

export default function App() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null);
  const [gridColumnApi, setGridColumnApi] = useState(null);


  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Paper square>
      <h1>Current Plans</h1>
      <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} style={{ color: 'black' }}>
        <Tab label="Medical" />
        <Tab label="Dental" />
        <Tab label="Vision" />
        <Tab label="Life and Disability" />
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
        </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
        </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
        Item Four
        </TabPanel>
    </Paper>
  )

}


function TabPanel(props) {

  const { children, value, index } = props;
  const [dataSet,setData]  = useState([]);

  

  if(value===0){
    console.log("value",value)
    const dataSet0 = [
      { make: "0", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
      { make: "0", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }, 
      { make: "0", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
      { make: "0", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
      { make: "0", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
      { make: "0", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
      { make: "0", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
      { make: "0", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
      { make: "0", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
      
    ]

    setData(dataSet0)

  }
  if(value===1){
    console.log("value",value)
    const dataSet1 = [
      { make: "1", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
      { make: "2", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
      { make: "3", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
      { make: "4", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
      { make: "5", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
      { make: "6", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }, 
      { make: "7", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
      { make: "8", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
      { make: "9", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
    ]

    setData(dataSet1)

    
  }
  if(value===2){
    console.log("value",value)
  }
  if(value===3){
    console.log("value",value)
  }


  return (
    <div>
      {
        value === index && (
          <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 1200 }}>
            <AgGridReact
              rowData={dataSet}>
              <AgGridColumn field="make"></AgGridColumn>
              <AgGridColumn field="model"></AgGridColumn>
              <AgGridColumn field="price"></AgGridColumn>
              <AgGridColumn field="make"></AgGridColumn>
              <AgGridColumn field="model"></AgGridColumn>
              <AgGridColumn field="price"></AgGridColumn>
              <AgGridColumn field="make"></AgGridColumn>
              <AgGridColumn field="model"></AgGridColumn>
              <AgGridColumn field="price"></AgGridColumn>
            </AgGridReact>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
    
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    setValueDataSet();
  },[value]);

  function setValueDataSet() {
    if (value === 0) {
      console.log("value", value);
      const dataSet0 = [
        { make: "0", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
        { make: "0", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
        { make: "0", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
        { make: "0", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
        { make: "0", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
        { make: "0", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
        { make: "0", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
        { make: "0", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
        { make: "0", model: "Celica", price: 35000 }
      ];

      setData(dataSet0);
    }
    if (value === 1) {
      console.log("value", value);
      const dataSet1 = [
        { make: "1", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
        { make: "2", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
        { make: "3", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
        { make: "4", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
        { make: "5", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
        { make: "6", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
        { make: "7", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
        { make: "8", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
        { make: "9", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
      ];

      setData(dataSet1);
    }
    if (value === 2) {
      console.log("value", value);
      setData([]);
    }
    if (value === 3) {
      console.log("value", value);
      setData([]);
    }
  }
```

**Work Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]